# Jquery execution sequence

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a function that submits a form to a mvc controller as follows -

```
function submitForm() {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Users/Index',
                data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() { 
                    $('.usersearchresult').fadeOut('fast', function () { $('.loadinggif').show(); }); 
                    },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.loadinggif').hide();
                    $('.usersearchresult').hide().html(response).fadeIn('normal');

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

This works fine except when the response comes back too quickly `$('.loadinggif').hide();` happens **after** `$('.usersearchresult').hide().html(response).fadeIn('normal');`

I tried different combinations of callback functions (`$('.loadinggif').hide();` calling `$('.usersearchresult').hide().html(response).fadeIn('normal');` on call back and even the other way around and the behavior is always the same.

I am new to jquery; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `fadeOut` animation hasn't completed if the response returns too quickly.

To fix this, use the `stop` method, which will end the animation:

```
success: function (response) {
    $('.usersearchresult').stop();
    $('.loadinggif').hide();
    $('.usersearchresult').hide().html(response).fadeIn('normal');

}
```

Note that `stop` will prevent callbacks from being called, so the `.loadinggif` will never show if the response comes back while the `fadeOut` animation is still running. It's easiest to call both `$('.usersearchresult').stop();` and `$('.loadinggif').hide();`. They are mutually exclusive states, so you could test if the loadinggif is showing and determine whether you should call `stop` or `hide`.

Comment: That's neat! That was the problem. Thank you!